# double type precision in C#

Tags: c#, types, double

I have this code in C#

```
double result = 480 - 460.8;
```

Why result is 19.199999999999989 instead of 19.2?

Comment: cause its double? you need to use Math.Round() instead if you want that

Comment: public static void Main()
    {
        double x = 480 - 460.8;
    }

Comment: I don't want to Round it.

Comment: Welcome to floating point issues.

Comment: This is why C# has a `decimal` type.

Answer (score 10):

you should format your double precision of the `result` output:

```
double result = 480 - 460.8; 
String.Format("{0:0.##}", result);
```

test example:

https://ideone.com/27OfP4

**update:**

there is another way without string formatting you can use method `Math.Round` with two digits after decimal place :

```
Math.Round(result,2);
```

example:

https://ideone.com/2Q6RPD

Comment: @Elham Azadfar read this tutorial about round method for double numbers : https://www.dotnetperls.com/math-round